Issue With Dotnet Grpc Clinet Connection With Server Running In Cloud Run
So the issue i am facing is below
ERROR IN GRPC CALL URL - Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error
so i'm running my dotnet grpc in cloud run. For kestrel i am not using TLS security as Cloud Run automatically terminates it
currently i am using below code for authenticated channel on client side ,so my doubt is am i suppose to use this?
 var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler().ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;, Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials) });
cause why i got this doubt is since i am not managing any TLS security,
or is the above issue caused by any other reason??
-> one more thing which i tried is ,earlier i had not given the port number with the server url which i was trying to connect from the client side but no use

Can you try using a known-good client gRPC client (I use gRPCurl; Postman is often cited) against your service to eliminate your client code? You don't include the details but you should be using the Cloud Run service's endpoint (gcloud run services describe ${SERVICE} --project=${PROJECT} --region=${REGION} --format="value(status.url)") (gRPCurl wants the https:// prefix dropped) and (port) :443 added.
